# Shakespeare in Classic Jewish Sources

Tags: books-generally, gentiles, history

Does anyone know of any references to Shakespeare, translations of his works, or anything related to Shakespeare in classic Rabbinic sources?

Comment: The term 'classic Rabbinic sources' usually applies to Rishonim (at the latest), a period which predates shakespeare significantly.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if this qualifies as a truly "classic" source, but there is a classic essay by R' Zevin about "[The Judgment of Shylock According to Halachah.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38809&pgnum=180)"

**Update:** It seems that Hebrewbooks has removed this sefer ([לאור ההלכה](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?144241&)) from their collection. I could not locate the article anywhere else online, except for a snippet view in Google Books [here](http://books.google.com/books?ei=JSWUT7P0OIbOUYy11NgN&cd=2&id=EI4PAQAAIAAJ&dq=%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94&q=%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A7#search_anchor). Also of likely interest are two articles discussing that essay: [1](http://www.yasharbooks.com/2005/01/pound-of-flesh.html), [2](http://www.mail-archive.com/daf-discuss@shemayisrael.co.il/msg01239.html).

Comment: I wanted to read that essay, but the link is broken. I searched a little, but couldn't find a replacement. Could someone revise the URL please?

Comment: @EllieK - see my update.

Comment: Thank you much for your prompt and helpful response. The snippet was, well, like all Google snippets (makes one feel even more curious)! Item 1 was a good starting point, item 2 was amazing. It expanded upon related issues that happened to be on my mind, pertaining to the Merchant of Venice, and a recent matter, coincidentally. Thank you again!

Comment: @EllieK - glad to help! :)

Answer (score 5):

See http://bdld.info/2010/09/14/the-baal-mussar-and-the-bard/ and http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/11/first-hebrew-translation-of-hamlets-to.html for starters.